# Jquery key press event not triggered on enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$("#username,#password").keypress(function(e)
    {
        //alert('');
        if(e.keyCode == 13)
        {
            signIn();
        }
    });
```

The keypress event not calling if the enter button is pressed.

Comment: do the selected elements exist when code is run?  If not use `on()` to delegate handler. If they exist..is code wrapped in `document.ready`

Comment: Any specific browser? Seems to be working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jVg2E/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using keyUp event.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DgD4j/1/)**

```
$("#username,#password").keyup(function(e){
        //alert('');
        if(e.keyCode == 13)
        {
            signIn();
        }
});
```

This is also working with keypress

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WcgBh/1/)**

```
$("#txt1").keypress(function(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        //signIn();
        alert("keypress");
    }
});​
```

Comment: Isn't that an argument against this answer?

Answer (score 2):

Key down is more appropriate:

```
$("#username,#password").keydown(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13)
        {
            signIn();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `e.which` instead of `e.keyCode` because this is what jQuery guarantees to be on event
2. Try `e.preventDefault()`, because without it (if they are in a form) the form submits
3. Maybe the best would be listening on form's `submit` event

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not the `signIn ();` function that's faulty? Because this seems to work just fine; http://jsfiddle.net/vDkBs/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use keypress and which statement:

```
$("#username,#password").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        //call here your function
    }
});
```